# App crash with startAnimating method

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiimageview, nsarray

I'm working on an application, where I use animations. To animate my images, I use some `NSArray` :

```
@property (retain) NSArray * imagePig1;
```

When I open the `UIViewController` for the first time, it works. If I open it a second time with the previous which open it, it works, but when I open once and re-open with another `ViewController`, it crashes and gives me an error like this :

[image: Crash message]

As you could see, I make this sort of code to animate my `UIImageView` :

```
-(void) AllocPigWithImage:(UIImageView *)ImagePig
{
    [ImagePig stopAnimating];
    [ImagePig setAnimationImages:_imagePig1];
    [ImagePig setAnimationRepeatCount:INFINITY];
    [ImagePig setAnimationDuration:(1/7)];
    [ImagePig startAnimating];
}
```

How to fix it please ?

Thanks !

EDIT : This is what i'm having when I step over all those breakpoints : crash. But don't know how to see what array is failing :/

[image: Fail]

Comment: don't need stopAnimating. just startAnimating..

Comment: I don't see an error, I see a breakpoint.

Comment: type 'breakpoint list' in console (without quotes) and hit Enter. This should give you a list of current breakpoints. Look for breakpoint 1.3 there - at least you will know this breakpoint's condition.

Comment: In my breakpoint list, i've only one breakpoint "All exceptions", which is by default no ?

Comment: need more information dude ..wat is the exception you are getting, if any ??

Comment: How could i see the exception ? Because i've only what's on the printscreen now :/

Comment: Are you sure that your array of images has images inside?

Comment: What is the size of those images?

Comment: I will see with the array if this could cause the crash

Comment: @user2057209 When you create UIImage you are not "opening" the image, this will happen when the UIImageView need to show it, thus if the image is too big it could create a memory warning, and if it is too much the system will close your app, check also image size

Comment: @Andrea Why would i need to check image size ?

Comment: I've edited, and add one picture to explain the final crash

Comment: Already explained..for memory, but as you updated the question this is not the case

Comment: The array that is failing is the array that you pass in the image view, as stated in the exception. Try to print out the contents of that array.

Comment: The problem comes from the CGImage wich was not correct when i changed some parameters by opening the view controller from another. Thnaks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I referred images as

```
self.imagePig1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgres.jpeg"]
                  ,[UIImage imageNamed:@"images.jpg"], nil];
```

and used your method

```
-(void) AllocPigWithImage:(UIImageView *)ImagePig
{
    [ImagePig stopAnimating];
    [ImagePig setAnimationImages:_imagePig1];
    [ImagePig setAnimationRepeatCount:INFINITY];
    [ImagePig setAnimationDuration:(1/7)];
    [ImagePig startAnimating];
}
```

which is not crashing for me . Please cross check your array allocation code . It must look like if you `NSLog`

```
2013-07-04 18:56:04.324 imageTest[9330:c07] (
    "<UIImage: 0x7178520>",
    "<UIImage: 0x71771d0>"
)
```

Comment: I'm going to see with the arrays, because it should come from here

Comment: One of my arrays is looks like to failed, but i don't know which. I've edited

Comment: please add code how you are adding images to the array , only that can help us to solve your problem

Comment: It comes from here, fail in adding if one condition isn't correct (and it was not when reloading the view controller), thanks